# after compiler jdk8 ,execute commond java -version ,jvm crash;

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

my after jdk8 sources compiler （make）(macos) ,
execute commond ”java -version“ ，jvm crash ；

execute make output:

```
## Finished docs (build time 00:01:52)

----- Build times -------
Start 2020-09-03 11:18:37
End   2020-09-03 11:30:07
00:00:19 corba
00:00:46 demos
00:01:52 docs
00:02:53 hotspot
00:01:28 images
00:00:12 jaxp
00:00:18 jaxws
00:03:07 jdk
00:00:26 langtools
00:00:09 nashorn
00:11:30 TOTAL
-------------------------
Finished building OpenJDK for target 'all'
```

execute commond java -version  output:

```
uochen-2:bin luochen$  ~/templete-open/jdk8/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-internal-luochen_2020_09_02_17_43-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x0000000105a479bd, pid=69932, tid=6915
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0) (build 1.8.0-internal-luochen_2020_09_02_17_43-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4479bd]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/hs_err_pid69932.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

[error occurred during error reporting , id 0x4]

Abort trap: 6
```

hs_err_pid69932.log

```
luochen-2:bin luochen$ cat /Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/bin/hs_err_pid69932.log
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x0000000105a479bd, pid=69932, tid=6915
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0) (build 1.8.0-internal-luochen_2020_09_02_17_43-b00)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4479bd]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

siginfo:si_signo=SIGILL: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (ILL_ILLOPC), si_addr=0x0000000105a479bd

Registers:
RAX=0x00000000000000f7, RBX=0x00007fa11ce07ab0, RCX=0x00007fa11e006600, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000070000e4ebd50, RBP=0x000070000e4ebd60, RSI=0x00007fa11e810a00, RDI=0x0000000104bc9a00
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00007fa11e800000, R10=0x0000000104bc13e0, R11=0x00007fa11e800000
R12=0x0000000105db4000, R13=0x0000000000000001, R14=0x00007fa11e811000, R15=0x00007fa11ce08e70
RIP=0x0000000105a479bd, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x0000000000000006

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000070000e4ebd50)
0x000070000e4ebd50:   0000000105db4298 00007fa11ce09370
0x000070000e4ebd60:   000070000e4ebd70 0000000105a489ff
0x000070000e4ebd70:   000070000e4ebd90 000000010586fac2
0x000070000e4ebd80:   0000000000001b00 00007fa11ce09370
0x000070000e4ebd90:   000070000e4ebdf0 0000000105aeb9ad
0x000070000e4ebda0:   0000000105b6a86b 000070000e4ebe18
0x000070000e4ebdb0:   00007fa11ce06d00 0000000000000001
0x000070000e4ebdc0:   000070000e4ebe00 00007fa11ce0b190
0x000070000e4ebdd0:   000070000e4ebdf0 00007fa11e811000
0x000070000e4ebde0:   0000000105daf883 0000000105db2ff0
0x000070000e4ebdf0:   000070000e4ebe40 00000001058c6289
0x000070000e4ebe00:   0000000000010008 0000000105b6a86b
0x000070000e4ebe10:   0000000000000000 00007fa11e8111d0
0x000070000e4ebe20:   0000000000000000 00007fa11ce06d00
0x000070000e4ebe30:   00007fa11d8029d0 00007fa11ce0b190
0x000070000e4ebe40:   000070000e4ebef0 0000000104ba830a
0x000070000e4ebe50:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebe60:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebe70:   0000000200010002 00007fa11ce06d30
0x000070000e4ebe80:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebe90:   0000000000000000 000001745232ba0f
0x000070000e4ebea0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebeb0:   00007fa11ce06cf8 00007fa11d8029d0
0x000070000e4ebec0:   0000000105d9b2a0 000070000e4ec000
0x000070000e4ebed0:   0000000104ba7c16 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebee0:   000070000e4ec000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebef0:   000070000e4ebf20 00007fff66817661
0x000070000e4ebf00:   0000000000000001 000070000e4ec000
0x000070000e4ebf10:   00000000180008ff 000070000e25ece0
0x000070000e4ebf20:   000070000e4ebf50 00007fff6681750d
0x000070000e4ebf30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000070000e4ebf40:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000105a479bd)
0x0000000105a4799d:   fd ff 31 c0 48 89 05 58 be 36 00 48 89 05 59 be
0x0000000105a479ad:   36 00 48 89 05 5a be 36 00 48 83 c4 08 5b 5d c3
0x0000000105a479bd:   0f 0b 90 55 48 89 e5 5d e9 1e 0c 00 00 55 48 89
0x0000000105a479cd:   e5 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 53 50 41 89 f7 49 89

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000000000000f7 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007fa11ce07ab0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00007fa11e006600 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000070000e4ebd50 is an unknown value
RBP=0x000070000e4ebd60 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00007fa11e810a00 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000104bc9a00 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007fa11e800000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000104bc13e0 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007fa11e800000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000105db4000: _ZN20SafepointSynchronize6_stateE+0 in /Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/build/macosx-x86_64-normal-server-release/jdk/lib/server/libjvm.dylib at 0x0000000105600000
R13=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007fa11e811000 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007fa11ce08e70 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000070000e3ec000,0x000070000e4ec000],  sp=0x000070000e4ebd50,  free space=1023k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4479bd]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4489ff]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x26fac2]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4eb9ad]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2c6289]
C  [java+0x330a]  JavaMain+0x6f4
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x3661]  _pthread_body+0x154
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x350d]  _pthread_body+0x0
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x2bf9]  thread_start+0xd


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

VM state:at safepoint (shutting down)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00007fa11ce08e70] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007fa11d854800

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 1024K, used 306K [0x0000000795580000, 0x0000000795700000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 512K, 59% used [0x0000000795580000,0x00000007955ccb98,0x0000000795600000)
  from space 512K, 0% used [0x0000000795680000,0x0000000795680000,0x0000000795700000)
  to   space 512K, 0% used [0x0000000795600000,0x0000000795600000,0x0000000795680000)
 ParOldGen       total 129536K, used 0K [0x0000000740000000, 0x0000000747e80000, 0x0000000795580000)
  object space 129536K, 0% used [0x0000000740000000,0x0000000740000000,0x0000000747e80000)
 Metaspace       used 2100K, capacity 4480K, committed 4480K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 224K, capacity 384K, committed 384K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000115b2b000,0x0000000115f2c000] byte_map_base: 0x000000011212b000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000105db3b38
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000115f2c000, 0x0000000117f2c000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000117f2c000, 0x0000000119f2c000)

Polling page: 0x0000000104c6e000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1054Kb max_used=1054Kb free=244705Kb
 bounds [0x0000000106b2b000, 0x0000000106d9b000, 0x0000000115b2b000]
 total_blobs=215 nmethods=2 adapters=130
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (2 events):
Event: 0.213 Thread 0x00007fa11d008800    1       3       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
Event: 0.214 Thread 0x00007fa11d008800 nmethod 1 0x0000000106c29350 code [0x0000000106c294e0, 0x0000000106c29a30]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.105 Thread 0x00007fa11d802800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x0000000795595310) thrown at [/Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp,
Event: 0.105 Thread 0x00007fa11d802800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000007955955a0) thrown at [/Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 3994]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.217 loading class java/nio/charset/CoderResult$1 done
Event: 0.217 loading class java/nio/charset/CoderResult$2
Event: 0.217 loading class java/nio/charset/CoderResult$2 done
Event: 0.218 Thread 0x00007fa11d802800 Thread exited: 0x00007fa11d802800
Event: 0.218 Thread 0x00007fa11e811000 Thread added: 0x00007fa11e811000
Event: 0.218 loading class java/lang/Shutdown
Event: 0.218 loading class java/lang/Shutdown done
Event: 0.218 loading class java/lang/Shutdown$Lock
Event: 0.219 loading class java/lang/Shutdown$Lock done
Event: 0.219 Thread 0x00007fa11e811000 Thread exited: 0x00007fa11e811000


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteViewServices.framework/Versions/A/RemoteViewServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/Versions/A/UIFoundation
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DFRFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DFRFoundation
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SkyLight.framework/Versions/A/SkyLight
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libScreenReader.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SignpostNotification.framework/Versions/A/SignpostNotification
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/closure/libclosured.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/loginsupport.framework/Versions/A/loginsupport
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/Versions/A/TCC
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSyncLegacy.framework/Versions/A/ColorSyncLegacy
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QD.framework/Versions/A/QD
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreDisplay.framework/Versions/A/CoreDisplay
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUWrangler.framework/Versions/A/GPUWrangler
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOPresentment.framework/Versions/A/IOPresentment
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DSExternalDisplay.framework/Versions/A/DSExternalDisplay
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphVisualizer.framework/Versions/A/GraphVisualizer
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/Versions/A/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libFosl_dynamic.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/Versions/A/FaceCore
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
0x0000000016660000     /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
0x0000000016660000     /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/Versions/A/AppleJPEG
0x0000000016660000     ........
VM Arguments:
java_command: <unknown>
java_class_path (initial): 
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
SHELL=/bin/bash

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.dylib+0x5223b1], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000043
SIGBUS: [libjvm.dylib+0x5223b1], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGFPE: [libjvm.dylib+0x422f57], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.dylib+0x422f57], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.dylib+0x422f57], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGILL: [libjvm.dylib+0x422f57], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x63807efb, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.dylib+0x4237e7], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGHUP: [libjvm.dylib+0x421b63], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGINT: [libjvm.dylib+0x421b63], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGTERM: [libjvm.dylib+0x421b63], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.dylib+0x421b63], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Bsduname:Darwin 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 709, NOFILE 10240, AS infinity
load average:1.44 1.68 1.83

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8388608k(172204k free)

/proc/meminfo:


vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.0-b70) for bsd-amd64 JRE (1.8.0-internal-luochen_2020_09_02_17_43-b00), built on Sep  3 2020 10:02:13 by "luochen" with gcc 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)

time: Thu Sep  3 12:15:26 2020
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

log exception

```
Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.105 Thread 0x00007fa11d802800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x0000000795595310) thrown at [/Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp,
Event: 0.105 Thread 0x00007fa11d802800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000007955955a0) thrown at [/Users/luochen/templete-open/jdk8/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp, line 3994]
```

Looks as if he has relationship with JNI compilation, whether with the need of the compilation and modification of part of the source code, compiled reference site:https://wangjun-scu.gitbooks.io/reading-notes/content/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0/JVM%E5%AD%A6%E4%B9%A0/%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E5%8A%A8%E6%89%8B%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91OPENJDK.html

How can I solve this problem? thanks！

Comment: Why do you need to compile JDK yourself? There are MacOS binaries available at https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot

Comment: Start from building debug JDK: `./configure --with-debug-level=slowdebug`. You'll likely see a meaningful assertion failure instead of a crash.

Answer (score 0):

A core dump is a file that records the memory image of a running process and its process status.
If you are compiling and running programs, and your program core dumps, remember to delete the file "core" because often it can be a very large file, which will cause you to hit your quota limit. Core files are binary files, that are created when a program dies.

If you try to enable writing core files, first run the following command to see all the resource limits for the current user.

```
$ ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1024
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 16384
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Now, to set ulimit for core dump to unlimited as mentioned in your logs, try (not as user root) to change the core file size to unlimited by running the following command on your system:

> $ ulimit -c unlimited

Comment: try ulimit -c unlimited Command，Still no, same exception

Comment: Are you compile with the same user as `ulimit -c unlimited`! And does it say Core dumps errors again or different error?! ensure you see `-c unlimited `  in your log.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals

> The SIGILL signal is raised when an attempt is made to execute an
> invalid, privileged, or ill-formed instruction. SIGILL is usually
> caused by a program error that overlays code with data or by a call to
> a function that is not linked into the program load module.

Looks like something went wrong during the compilation.